# DMA on STM32F4 doesn't work, is my configuration wrong?

Tags: configuration, stm32, dma, adc

I'm working on a project for a digital filter, see figure below. I have timer 3 triggering the ADC at 40kHz, the ADC should then make a sample and when its conversion is done it should trigger the DMA. The DMA should then move the converted value from the ADC peripheral memory to a memory address. Timer 3 works fine, however the DMA_IRQHandler code doesn't seem to work. 
Does anybody know if my configuration of the DMA or the ADC is wrong? My code is depicted below.

Many thanks!

[image: block diagram code]

```
void timer_init (void)
{
    RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM3, ENABLE);

    TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef timerInitStructure;
    timerInitStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 0;
    timerInitStructure.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;
    timerInitStructure.TIM_Period = 1050*2; // Sample frequentie, 40kHz
    timerInitStructure.TIM_ClockDivision = TIM_CKD_DIV1;
    timerInitStructure.TIM_RepetitionCounter = 0;
    TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM3, &timerInitStructure);
    TIM_Cmd(TIM3, ENABLE);

    TIM_SelectOutputTrigger(TIM3, TIM_TRGOSource_Update);
}

void timer_interrupt_init (void)
{
  NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;
  /* Enable the timer global Interrupt */
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = TIM3_IRQn;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 2;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0;
  NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
  NVIC_Init (&NVIC_InitStructure);

  //NVIC_SetPriority(TIM3_IRQn, 2);
}

void timer_start (void)
{
  TIM_Cmd (TIM3, ENABLE);
}

void timer_stop (void)
{
  TIM_Cmd (TIM3, DISABLE);
}

void timer_interrupt_enable (void)
{
  /*
   * It is important to clear any pending interrupt flags since the timer
   * has been free-running since we last used it and that will generate
   * interrupts on overflow even though the associated interrupt event has
   * not been enabled.
   */
  TIM_ClearITPendingBit (TIM3, TIM_IT_Update);
  /* put the counter into a known state */
  TIM_SetCounter (TIM3, 0);
  TIM_ITConfig (TIM3, TIM_IT_Update, ENABLE);
}

void timer_interrupt_disable (void)
{
  TIM_ITConfig (TIM3, TIM_IT_Update, DISABLE);
}

void TIM3_IRQHandler (void)
{
  if (TIM_GetITStatus (TIM3, TIM_IT_Update) != RESET)
  {
      //GPIO_ToggleBits(GPIOD, GREEN_PIN); // For checking the timer frequency with a scope
      TIM_ClearITPendingBit(TIM3, TIM_IT_Update);
  }
}

void adc_init(void)
{
    RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_ADC2, ENABLE); // Enable the clock for the ADC peripheral
    RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOC, ENABLE);// Enable the clock for the GPIO peripheral

    // Configure GPIO PC1 to analog mode
    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_1; 
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AN;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL ;
    GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);

    // Configure the common adc parameters
    ADC_CommonInitTypeDef ADC_CommonInitStruct;
    ADC_CommonInitStruct.ADC_Mode = ADC_Mode_Independent;
    ADC_CommonInitStruct.ADC_Prescaler = ADC_Prescaler_Div2;
    ADC_CommonInitStruct.ADC_DMAAccessMode = ADC_DMAAccessMode_Disabled;
    ADC_CommonInitStruct.ADC_TwoSamplingDelay = ADC_TwoSamplingDelay_5Cycles;

    ADC_CommonInit(&ADC_CommonInitStruct);

    // Configure the specific adc parameters
    ADC_InitTypeDef ADC_InitStruct;
    ADC_InitStruct.ADC_Resolution = ADC_Resolution_12b;
    ADC_InitStruct.ADC_DataAlign  = ADC_DataAlign_Right;
    ADC_InitStruct.ADC_ScanConvMode = DISABLE;
    ADC_InitStruct.ADC_ContinuousConvMode = DISABLE;
    ADC_InitStruct.ADC_ExternalTrigConvEdge = ADC_ExternalTrigConvEdge_Rising;
    ADC_InitStruct.ADC_ExternalTrigConv = ADC_ExternalTrigConv_T3_TRGO; // ADC gets triggered by timer 3
    ADC_InitStruct.ADC_NbrOfConversion = 1; // single conversion

    ADC_Init(ADC2, &ADC_InitStruct);

    ADC_RegularChannelConfig(ADC2, ADC_Channel_11, 1, ADC_SampleTime_3Cycles);

    ADC_DMARequestAfterLastTransferCmd(ADC2, ENABLE);
    ADC_DMACmd(ADC2, ENABLE);
    ADC_Cmd(ADC2, ENABLE);
}

void DMA_Initialize(void)
{
    RCC_AHB1PeriphResetCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_DMA2, ENABLE);
    DMA_InitTypeDef DMA_InitStructure;

    /* Initialise DMA */
    DMA_StructInit(&DMA_InitStructure);
    DMA_DeInit(DMA2_Stream3);  //Set DMA registers to default values

    /* config of DMAC */
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Channel = DMA_Channel_1; /* This channel is linked to ADC2*/
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_BufferSize = 1; /* Size in words of the buffer where the adc sample value gets stored */
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_DIR = DMA_DIR_PeripheralToMemory; /* direction */
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_FIFOMode = DMA_FIFOMode_Disable; /* no FIFO */
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_FIFOThreshold = DMA_FIFOThreshold_HalfFull;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryBurst = DMA_MemoryBurst_Single;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBurst = DMA_PeripheralBurst_Single;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Mode = DMA_Mode_Normal; /* here you van select normal mode or circular buffer */
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Priority = DMA_Priority_High; /* here you can select the priority of the dma stream. */

    /* config of memory */
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_Memory0BaseAddr = (uint32_t)&ADC_value; /* target addr */
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryDataSize = DMA_MemoryDataSize_HalfWord; //DMA_MemoryDataSize_Word /* 16 bit */
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_MemoryInc = DMA_MemoryInc_Disable;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralBaseAddr = (uint32_t)&ADC2->DR;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralDataSize = DMA_PeripheralDataSize_HalfWord;
    DMA_InitStructure.DMA_PeripheralInc = DMA_PeripheralInc_Disable;

    DMA_Init(DMA2_Stream3, &DMA_InitStructure); /* See Table 20 for mapping */
    DMA_Cmd(DMA2_Stream3, ENABLE);
    DMA_ITConfig(DMA2_Stream3,DMA_IT_TC, ENABLE);
}

void DMA2_Stream3_IRQHandler()
{
    if(DMA_GetITStatus(DMA2_Stream3, DMA_IT_TCIF3) != RESET)
    {
        DMA_ClearITPendingBit(DMA2_Stream3, DMA_IT_TCIF3);
        GPIO_ToggleBits(GPIOD, RED_PIN);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use registers. Will be easier and much better

Comment: Your graph is wrong: should be Timer -> Trigger -> ADC -> DMA -> interrupt at the end of the transmition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the NVIC configuration for DMA is missing. I guess something like this before DMA_ITConfig(DMA2_Stream3,DMA_IT_TC, ENABLE);

```
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = DMA2_Channel1_IRQn;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 0;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0x01;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);
DMA_ITConfig(DMA2_Channel1, DMA_IT_TC, ENABLE);
```

also, call this part before DMA_Cmd(DMA2_Stream3, ENABLE);